# The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, types, incompatibility

```
  class A {
        public A get() { }
 }

 class B extends A {

 }
```

The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods,
how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: sorry, corrected the example ;@

Comment: You want to write something like `B b = new B().get();` without explicit casting?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the code snippet you pasted in doesn't compile. `public A get()` has a return type but is returning nothing for starters...

Comment: Which return types? Whole compiler message with line numbers, and where they refer to. Make a short example where we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

From JDK 5, Java allow you to alter the return type of an overridden method, as long as the new type is a subclass of the original one. 
This is called [covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).
Following code will compile correctly:

```
class A {

    A get() {
        return new A();
    }

    void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello");    
    }
}

class B extends A {

    @Override
    B get() {
        return new B();
    }

    void sayGoodbye(){
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
}

class Test{
    void check(){
        B two=new B();
        two.get().sayGoodbye();
    } 
}
```

Remember that the return type of the overridden method should be a subclass of the return type, to allow you to call the method on A variables and get a valid A object (which is infact a B instance):

```
        void check(){
            A two=new B();
            A copy=two.get();
            copy.sayHello();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
 class A<T extends A> {
        public T get() { }
 }

 class B extends A<B> {

 }

B b = new B();
B got = b.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to write something like `B b = new B().get();` without explicit typecasting like Nikita Beloglazov suggests, though that's not an idiom that Java supports well. Eugene's answer works well enough, though that still involves a cast to `T` and generates an ugly compiler warning besides. Personally, I would write code more like the following:

```
class A {
    private A() {}

    public A get() {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private B() {}

    @Override
    public A get() {
        return new B();
    }

    public B getB() {
        return (B) get();
    }
}
```

You still can't do `B b = new B().get();`, but you can do `B b = new B().getB();`, which is just as easy and a bit more self-documenting anyways, since you already know you want a `B` object, not just any `A` object. And `A a = new B().get();` would create a B object, albeit one that only has access to the methods declared in `A`.